# How Can I Solve Turkish Character Encoding on Html Source?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, character-encoding

I have problem with Turkish characters..

When I write `Üye Ol` it looks good, but in the source codes of html it looks `&#220;ye Ol`

It can solve with Html.Raw() but I don't want to use it everywhere.. Is there any solitoun??

Comment: Is there any special reason why HTML entities are problem for you? The HTML document with these entities is perfectly valid and I have never had problem with them.

Comment: Because my project's first language is Turkish and almost all data comes from database.. If I could not find any solution, I have to use it everywhere.. It doesn't seem like such a good idea..

Comment: Did you find any solutions for this problem?